# Show that the function $f(A)={(\det_1 A, \det_2 A, \dots , \det_n A)}^T$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and let the function $f: M_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ s.t $f(A)={(\det_1 A, \det_2 A, \dots , \det_n A)}^T$ where $\det_n A$ is the $n$-th minor determinant of $A$, I need to show that this function is continuous.

Comment: What's the problem? It's just a polynomial in the matrix entries, isn't it?

Comment: You only have two show that each $\det_k$ is continuous.  But those are all polynomials of the components of $A$.

Comment: Where is the question coming from? Are you taking a calculus course where you need to justify continuity in details?

Comment: I just need understand it and make a simple proof. And yes, i know that if each $\det_n$ is continuos is done. But i dont know which is this polynomial that you say